# What's the unity equivalent of gnome's ALT-F2?

Tags: unity

How do you run any command in Unity, similar to "Run command" (ALT-F2) from Gnome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly the same - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: Wow, of course it is :)
I've typed 'sudo gnome-terminal' and nothing happened. Of course, using gksudo works...